# Do you know that ≥90% Python tutorials of the float() function is wrong?

Tags: python, nan, infinity

Do you know that **≥90%** Python tutorials of the `float()` function are wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes!
Many state this:

> It is invalid to give strings like `"abc"`, `"Hello"` to `float()`.

No no no! Test this:
[image: Tested on Python 3.8.2 of Windows 10 1909 64-bit]
**Yes! There's actually ∞ and NaN in Python!**
But this is invalid for `int()` and `complex()`.
So you can write a subclass of `float` to let the `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__` methods return `float("inf")` when `ZeroDivisionError` is raised and maybe return `float("NaN")` if `ValueError` is raised in all of the magic math methods!

This is stated in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). But ≥70% people don't know it!

P.S. Do you like JavaScript? Now you can get the similar behavior!

Comment: If you need to add additional information to your question then you should [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/204922) your original question. Please only use the "Post Answer" button if you have found an answer to your question.

Additionally, this post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center*.